# Ubuntu 10.04 - Python multiprocessing - 'module' object has no attribute 'local' error

Tags: multiprocessing, ubuntu-10.04, python-2.6

The following code is from the python 2.6 manual.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os

def info(title):
    print(title)
    print('module name:', 'me')
    print('parent process:', os.getppid())
    print('process id:', os.getpid())

def f(name):
    info('function f')
    print('hello', name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    info('main line')
    p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

This creates the following stack traces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 1, in <module>
    from multiprocessing import Process
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 287, in <module>
    class ForkAwareLocal(threading.local):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'local'
Exception AttributeError: '_shutdown' in <module 'threading' from '/home/v0idnull/tmp/pythreads/threading.pyc'> ignored
Error in atexit._run_exitfuncs:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 258, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Error in sys.exitfunc:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
    func(*targs, **kargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 258, in _exit_function
    info('process shutting down')
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I'm completely clueless as to WHY this is happening, and google has given me very little to work with.

Answer (score 6):

that code runs fine on my machine:
Ubuntu 10.10, Python 2.6.6 64-bit.

but your error is actually because you have a file named 'threading.py' that you are running this code from (see the stack-trace details).  this is causing a namespace mismatch, since the multiprocessing module needs the 'real' threading module.  try renaming your file to something other than 'threading.py' and running it again.

also... the example you posted is not from the Python 2.6 docs... it is from the Python 3.x docs.  make sure you are reading the docs for the version that matches what you are running.